# How to automatically search and filters all engineers from linkedin and store results in excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, api, parsing, linkedin-api

Does anyone know how i can parse LinkedIn accounts? Or Any tool( not paid ).
For example:
I will look for "Software Engineer" from Dallas,TX.
Tool will automatically pick all candidates from linkedin or for example first 100 candidates, and store their First Name, Last Name , LinkedinLink and Experience in excel document? ( Or from specific company)
Is it should be done threw API, or there specific account which allow to do this? Or does anyone knows tools which will help to do this? Or Script?

I need to parse a large amount of candidates , 100+ maybe 1000+  and store them.
I have multiple thoughts about implementation but i feel that it 100% already implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Use linked in APIs to fetch data and process it however you would like. I don't know how much of 'private' fields you can get access to but names seem to be there.

I use nodeJS to process excel data - `xlsx` is a very good option but it only allows synchronous execution so you would have to spawn another process. It also has filter function so you can do whatever you want with it.

The problem that I had faced with parsing large data into excel is that excel file is a compressed xml format so it takes a long time to parse both reading and writing. A faster option would be to create and read csv which excel can naturally do as well.